# JQuery to move to page Top while refreshing the page

Tags: jquery

jQuery to move to page top on page refresh. I have set the window scroll top to 0. Also tried something like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 300);
```

Found this was working in all the other browser except chrome. I need a solution that should work in all the browser.

Comment: Tried it in Chrome and it ... worked!(?). Does anything at all happen like console error or the page just does not scroll? Maybe Chrome does the scrolling before you can see it/before DOM is ready?

Answer (score 0):

Due to cross browser issue, best solution for you will be

```
if($.browser.safari)
{
    loc = $("body")
}
else
{ 
    loc = $("html,body")
}      
loc.scrollTop(100)
```

Or Try it without animation simply,

```
jQuery('html, body').scrollTop(0);
```

OR try any of these that work for you!!

```
jQuery('body').scrollTop(0);

jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);

jQuery('html').scrollTop(0);

window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

Comment: Thanks Gautam , I have tried all the above mentioned code .Still it is not working . While refreshing the page first time, it is going to the top of the page . But after the page load complete again it is setting the old position. Issue only in Chrome

Comment: what is the version of chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
});
```